# Algorithm to return arg_min and optionally min_val

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I made a simple `arg min` function based on a couple of STL algorithms:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryOperation>
ForwardIt arg_min(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryOperation unary_op)
{
  if (first == last) return last; //we were passed an empty container

  ForwardIt smallest = first; // iterator to the element that results in 
                              // the smallest value returned by unary_op
  auto smallest_val = unary_op(*first); //the actual smallest value

  ++first;
  for (; first != last; ++first) {
    auto first_val = unary_op(*first);
    if (first_val < smallest_val) {    // if unary_op returns a smaller than our current smallest value,
      smallest = first;                // store the iterator to the arg
      smallest_val = first_val;        // and the value itself
    }
  }
  return smallest;
}
```

and it works pretty fantastic. However, I knew the time would come that I'd want to get the actual min value back as well as the argument that results in that value.  I could just re-run the returned argument through the `UnaryOperation` function, but that's kind of sub-optimal.

I guess there are two strategies - 1) pass in a pointer to the value type that the function then fills in or 2) return a std::pair. I don't really like either option since returning the value generated by the arg min element should be optional. For option (1) my initial thought was something like:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryOperation, class MinVal>
ForwardIt arg_min(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryOperation unary_op, MinVal* p_min_val = nullptr)
{
  if (first == last) return last;

  MinVal min_val;

  if(p_min_val == nullptr){
    p_min_val = &min_val;
  }

  ForwardIt smallest = first;
  *p_smallest_val = unary_op(*first);

  ++first;
  for (; first != last; ++first) {
    auto first_val = unary_op(*first);
    if (first_val < smallest_val) {
      smallest = first;
      *p_smallest_val = first_val;
    }
  }
  return smallest;
}
```

I don't think that will work because if `p_min_val` is `nullptr` then there's no way to deduce the type `MinVal`.

Option 2, I'm not sure how to make it return either just `smallest` or both `smallest` and `min_val`.

The only other thing I can thing of is just to define the function twice - once for each case.  Not a terrible option since it's pretty small--I was just wondering if there was another way. Is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, this is want I came up with:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryOperation>
auto arg_min(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryOperation unary_op) ->
  std::pair<ForwardIt, std::optional<std::decay_t<decltype(unary_op(*first))>>>
{
  if (first == last) return {last,{}}; //we were passed an empty container

  ForwardIt smallest = first; // iterator to the element that results in 
                              // the smallest value returned by unary_op
  auto smallest_val = unary_op(*first); //the actual smallest value

  ++first;
  for (; first != last; ++first) {
    auto first_val = unary_op(*first);
    if (first_val < smallest_val) {        // if unary_op returns a smaller than our current smallest value,
      smallest = first;                    // store the iterator to the arg
      smallest_val = std::move(first_val); // and the value itself
    }
  }
  return {smallest, smallest_val};
}
```

I think it'll work with any type that has a less than operator and is default constructible.  It can be seen in action here: https://godbolt.org/z/Gn386P

Answer (score 1):

My advice? return the `pair`. Let the caller decide if they want the min projected value. You've already calculated it - it's a shame for you, who doesn't know the caller's intention, to throw it away.

Want just the iterator? `auto iter = arg_min(first, last, op).first;`

Want just the min value? `auto value = *arg_min(first, last, op).first;`

Want just the min projected value? `auto pValue = arg_min(first, last, op).second;`

Comment: Ok, but there are some issues with saying "just return a `pair`." I agree, but you have to specify the actual type, which I think was what the OP was tripping up on in the first place thinking about this option. The function would return `std::pair<ForwardIt, std::optional<std::decay_t<decltype(unary_op(*first))>>>`, which is not at all obvious (to the point where I'm not sure whether it's quite right).

Comment: E.g. here's how I'd [actually implement](https://godbolt.org/z/txA_pH) this answer. @OP, note that your original algorithm is missing a `std::move`: it should be `smallest_val = std::move(first_val)` in the loop.

Comment: @HTNW, that's not right. Forget the `optional` bit. There's no need for that. You're going to have one of them anyway.

Comment: @HTNW - I see why you want `optional`, for the case where `first == last`.

Comment: Yes, that was my intent to let the caller decide whether or not they wanted it while avoiding having to recompute it.  Would it be reasonable to assume that the type of the min value was default constructible and return a default constructed instance in the event an empty container is passed instead of a `std::optional`?  The caller could still test if the iterator that's returned is equal to `end()` to see  whether or not the algorithm failed. I guess `std::optional` still gives it better ergonomics.

Comment: P.S. - Yes, the thing I was hung up on was deducing the min value type.  Here's an example of this working with your suggestions: https://godbolt.org/z/Gn386P. I think I'll call that an answer if you want to update it with the code that deduces the type.